# MySQL - Hash an entire queryset

Tags: mysql, hash

Let's say I have a query that is run all 15min.
I just need to know if the resulting data have been modified since the last fetch.
So I though to get a hash from the result to be able to compare.
I know how to hash a single record, but I have no idea to do it for multiple records.

- Is it a best practice to hash an entire queryset ?
- How can I do it ?

Comment: May you can add other table to track changes with MySQL's `TRIGGER`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRIGGERs seem to be the closest solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing hashes, why not use timestamps intelligently? Each record in your table can have a created_at and updated_at attribute. created_at is set when a new record is inserted. updated_at is updated when the record is updated.

Every time you fetch the data, you register the current timestamp as, say, TS. To see if any new records are available for the next fetch, run:

```
select count(*) from table where created_at>TS or updated_at>TS
```

Count operations are relatively cheaper.

Comment: I thought about that but what to do if there is a row deleted ?

Comment: @Glide- Maintain a count of the rows somewhere?

Comment: You will have the same number of rows if you delete one and add another

Comment: Hmm, true. Maintain both count of rows and highest ID?

Comment: If you query a range that is not part of the latest rows, the latest ID will not tell you if there is a deleted row into the range.